# How to run JavaScript code in VSCode's terminal?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, terminal

I want to test small snippets of JavaScript code in VSCode's terminal before inserting them in my project.  I want something similar to Chrome's Devtools console.

Comment: Just create a test file and and execute the test file.

Comment: @HereticMonkey that thread dismissed a quite valid solution to use node, which requires zero plugins installed for VSC.

Comment: @crtag "dismissed"? There is no dismissal in Stack Overflow. Add an answer to that question that suggests using NodeJS or upvote the one that obliquely does already.

Comment: @HereticMonkey for some reason I was thinking this was for node...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn A lot of chatter about using node as a solution in the answers and comments, I can see why :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes that is the same question, but it does not contain the word "terminal" anywhere, maybe that is why I could not find it via googling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install node and npm from https://nodejs.org/en/download/

After installation in VSCode under terminal tab run
`node`
Paste your snippet to run your javascript code or use `node filepath/filename.js` to see result.

Answer (score 4):

Just run the command `node` to enter a node environment where you can run arbitrary JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Run node in the VSC console and you will have the same experience